# Detecting object Water Reservoir

Tags: sensor, light-sensor, sensing

You have this large water reservoir, for example, a bathtub. How can you detect when an object is thrown (rock, etc) into a big water reservoir? Vibrating sensor, ultrasonic etc?

Comment: Microphone listening for a splash?

Comment: yeah a microphone seems a good idea to me, plus it's very cheap. this question isn't much about electronics design though...

Comment: microphone or hydrophone should work

Comment: How big is the reservoir? When you say large and reservoir, I think 'pond' as a minimum, not bathtub.  Acoustics would work in the bathtub, but probably not the pond.  Perhaps a pressure sensor, or an array of them for larger containments.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use a simple accelerometer, since there may be background noise like wind,etc. Just put it on a floating little buoy of sorts.

Comment: I had the same idea. I think you don't necessarily need a accelerometer though.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way on my opinion would be to catch the waves on the surface of the liquid(water). Could b easily done even with a mechanic switch anchored to the side at the surface level and a piece of Styrofoam, which following the waves will move up and down and turn the switch on and off,  or at the bottom and via a string and a piece of styrofoam  floating on the surface and pulling and loosening the string/cord while waves are present .